# Getting size of aliased std::array?

Tags: c++

Consider, for example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Ram_bank = std::array<char, 0x2000>;
    std::cout << "Size of ram bank is: " << Ram_bank::size() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this is not valid code, as `Ram_bank` is not an actual type or object but an alias. But, is there some way to achieve this? Is there a way to get the size of an aliased type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is not failing because `Ram_bank` is an alias. It is failing because `size()` is non-static and you would need an instance to call it on. Kosta's answer is an example of that.

Alternatively, you can use `std::tuple_size`:

```
std::cout << "Size of ram bank is: " << std::tuple_size<Ram_bank>::value << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instantiate an array and then take it's size (since `std::array::size` is a non-static member function). Every half-decent compiler should optimize this away:

```
std::cout << "Size of ram bank is: " << Ram_bank().size() << '\n';
```